# Pandas: set all values that are <= 0 to the maximum value in a column by group, but only after the last positive value in that group

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to set all values that are <= 0, by group, to the maximum value in that group, but only after the last positive value. That is, all values <=0 in the group that come before the last positive value must be ignored. Example:

```
data = {'group':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 
                'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
                 'value':[3, 0, 8, 7, 0, -1, 0, 9, -2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0, 1]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

  group  value
0   A      3
1   A      0
2   A      8
3   A      7
4   A      0
5   B     -1
6   B      0
7   B      9
8   B     -2
9   B      0
10  B      0
11  C      2
12  C      0
13  C      5
14  C      0
15  C      1
```

and the result must be:

```
  group  value
0   A      3
1   A      0
2   A      8
3   A      7
4   A      8
5   B     -1
6   B      0
7   B      9
8   B      9
9   B      9
10  B      9
11  C      2
12  C      0
13  C      5
14  C      0
15  C      1
```

Thanks to advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by adding a column to identify the rows with negative value (more precisely <= 0):

```
df['neg'] = (df['value'] <= 0)
```

Then, for each group, find the sequence of last few entries that have `'neg'` set to True and that are contiguous. In order to do that, reverse the order of the DataFrame (with `.iloc[::-1]`) and then use `.cumprod()` on the `'neg'` column. `cumprod()` will treat True as 1 and False as 0, so the cumulative product will be 1 as long as you're seeing all True's and will become and stay 0 as soon as you see the first False. Since we reversed the order, we're going backwards from the end, so we're finding the sequence of True's at the end.

```
df['upd'] = df.iloc[::-1].groupby('group')['neg'].cumprod().astype(bool)
```

Now that we know which entries to update, we just need to know what to update them to, which is the max of the group. We can use `transform('max')` on a groupby to get that value and then all that's left is to do the actual update of `'value'` where `'upd'` is set:

```
df.loc[df['upd'], 'value'] = df.groupby('group')['value'].transform('max')
```

We can finish by dropping the two auxiliary columns we used in the process:

```
df = df.drop(['neg', 'upd'], axis=1)
```

The result I got matches your expected result.

---

**UPDATE:** Or do the whole operation in a single (long!) line, without adding any auxiliary columns to the original DataFrame:

```
df.loc[
    df.assign(
        neg=(df['value'] <= 0)
    ).iloc[::-1].groupby(
        'group'
    )['neg'].cumprod().astype(bool),
    'value'
] = df.groupby(
    'group'
)['value'].transform('max')
```

Comment: Clever. Thanks. Avoided the join to make it looker cleaner: `df.loc[df['upd'], 'value'] = df.groupby('group')['value'].transform('max')`

Comment: @nrcjea001 Ah nice! This is what I was looking for... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way.

```
(df.loc[(df.assign(m=df['value'].lt(0)).groupby(['group'], sort=False)['m'].transform('any')) &
    (df.index>=df.groupby('group')['value'].transform('idxmin')),'value']) = np.nan
df['value']=df.groupby('group').ffill()
df
```

**Output**

```
group   value
0   A   3.0
1   A   0.0
2   A   8.0
3   A   7.0
4   A   0.0
5   B   -1.0
6   B   0.0
7   B   9.0
8   B   9.0
9   B   9.0
10  B   9.0
11  C   2.0
12  C   0.0
13  C   5.0
14  C   0.0
15  C   1.0
```

Comment: This is almost right. The last value in group A should be 8, not zero.